# HTML with AJAX requests to python files : server-side not executed

Tags: python, html, ajax, http

I want to deliver HTML files with AJAX requests (to a server-side scripting language) on a RedHat server where I don't have root access. I can't install HTTP server like *Apache* or *Nginx* and can't install *PHP* too.
So I thought using Python already included in the RedHat distribution.

Here is the HTML (+ jQuery) code :

```
<script>
function start_ajax_request(){
    $.get("request.py", function(data,status){
        alert(status);
        console.log(data);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    start_ajax_request();
});
</script>
```

---

**1 -** I used the built-in HTTP server (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`), but the Python code isn't executed, the source code of the py file is returned by the AJAX request :

```
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*

import json
print json.dumps({"a": 15, "b": 13, "c": 17})
```

**2 -** I made some tests with [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/). It doesn't seem the perfect tool to deliver HTML files (I don't need the framework thing).
When I launch the page in the brower, the AJAX request returns the source code of the py file too.

**3 -** I tried to use [Waitress](https://pylons.readthedocs.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/). It seemed more adapted to my needs, but I can't make it works.

---

What do I need to do to get the python file executed when an AJAX request is made ?
Is this a HTTP server problem or my code is not correct ?

I want to keep things simple and not invasive. I know practically nothing about Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very well SimpleHTTPServer, i use cherrypy to serve web pages; anyway: is request.py executable? First lines of python are like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
```